# No connection in a multicontainer docker environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, rabbitmq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy an application in Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2. I am using a pipeline, which publishes images to a private repository on Dockerhub. Elastic beanstalk uses docker-compose to run containers, but so far I've had no success in accessing the application. I am not using a dockerrun.aws.json file, as v.3 does not support any container configuration, and as far as I know, it's not needed for docker compose.

My docker-compose file contains several services, one of which is a RabbitMQ message broker.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    Some.API:
        image: ...
        container_name: some-api
        networks:
          - my-network
        ports:
          - "9002:80"

    Another.API:
        image: ...
        container_name: another-api
        networks:
          - my-network
        ports:
          - "9003:80"

    rabbitmQ:
        image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
        container_name: rabbit-mq
        labels:
          NAME: rabbitmq
        volumes:
          - ./rabbitconfig/rabbitmq-isolated.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
        networks:
         - my-network
        ports:
          - "4369:4369"
          - "5671:5671"
          - "5672:5672"
          - "25672:25672"
          - "15671:15671"
          - "15672:15672"

    front-end:
        image: ...
        container_name: front-end
        networks:
         - my-network
        ports:
         - "9001:80"

networks:
    my-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Once the current version of the application is successfuly deployed to Beanstalk, I see that there is no successful communication in the bridge network.
In the eb-stdouterr.log I see that there are errors while establishing connection between the apis and the message broker:
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable.

The APIs are .NET Core applications, which use the Beanstalk's environment variables to determine the name of the broker service. In the Configuration/Software/Environment properties section there is a following entry:

```
RABBIT_HOSTNAME | rabbitmq
```

which should ensure that the services use a proper host name.
Yet, I get exceptions. Any advice?

Comment: If you are using one ec2 instance on which you set up this exact docker-compose config, then the hostname should still be rabbitmQ (mind the capitals!). Why would it be something different ? I have no experience using elastic beanstalk, but it seems to me that it should be no different since you are not using ECS for instance. And if you are using the communication within the network there is no need to publish those ports.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed to reference the automatically generated .env file in docker-compose.yml like so:

```
front-end:
        image: ...
        container_name: front-end
        networks:
         - my-network
        ports:
         - "9001:80"
        env_file:          <--- these
          - .env           <--- 2 lines
```

for each service. Only after doing this the Environment properties from AWS Beanstalk were passed to the containers.